# Non-transitive dice generation method.

Tags: number-theory

I'm an eight grader, and one day, while I was bored in Algebra II, I started to screw around with the Thue-Morse sequence.  For those of you who don't know, the Thue-Morse sequence is a sequence generated by starting with an 1 and replacing every 1 with 1,2 and every 2 with 2,1.  Therefore, you start with 1, then get 1,2; 1,2,2,1; 1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2; 1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1.  Notice that when doing that the terms at the begging don't change, it only adds to the length of the sequence.  I tried starting with 1, replacing every 1 with 1,2,3, every 2 with 2,3,1 and every 3 with 3,1,2.  I generated the first 9 terms of the series and wrote them above the integers from 1 to 9 like so:

1,2,3,2,3,1,3,1,2

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Then I assigned the integer list to three groups according the number above it.  I got groups A:{1,6,8}, B:{2,4,9}, and C:{3,5,7}.  By luck I noticed that this would form a set of three non-transitive three-sided dice, where C tends to beat B, which tends to beat A, which tends to beat C.  For sticklers who would point out that there are no 3D three-sided platonic shapes, you can make each of them appear twice on a cube, and if you don't want there to be any repetitions you can double each number and add 1 to the second apparition of each number. I tried again with a four-symbol sequence where 1=1,2,3,4; 2=2,3,1,4; 3=3,4,1,2; and 4=4,1,2,3; and to my surprise, this worked again when I wrote out the first sixteen integers.  I tried this will all the numbers up to nine, each time writing out the n-symbol variation and the first n^2 integers, and each time it worked.  And so I am seeking the online communities for help:  First, although I could not find any mention to anything like this on this or other sites, is this already known, and secondly, if it is not, prove that this always works for n>2.

Footnote:  This obviously cannot work for two because of the very definition of non-transitive dice.  You cannot have a set of dice such that A tends to beat B which tends to beat A.  However, if this works for any n>2, then you can construct a set of n n-sided non-transitive dice.  Additionally, you can make the dice any multiple of n-sided by doing similarly as I did too the three-sided set.  Because there will be ties in any even-sized set when using this method, you could make an odd-sided that is a factor of n and turn it into a collection of n-sided dice, as long as n is not a power of two.

Comment: I have published on an extension of Efron's non-transitive dice:  *Lake Wobegon Dice*, where *each* die is more likely to roll above the set average than below the set average... and have never seen this algorithmic method for generating non-transitive dice.  I wonder if the core idea could be extended to $k>3$ dice.

Comment: In case this was not sufficiently clear, I make an n-symbol variant of the Thue-Morse sequence, which means that I am grouping the integers from 1 to n^2 into n groups.

Comment: This means that there are n dice in the set.  If you double the numbers on all the dice, and copy each die, and then add 1 to the second of each pair of dice, the second of each pair behaves with all the other dice as the first does, but tends to beat the first.  Doing similarly with 3 copies of each dice by multiplying by three and adding 1 to one die, 2 to a second, and leaving one unchanged gives you a set of dice three times as big as the number of sides on the die, or, by multiplying all the dice by three but only making copies of some of them you can make sets any size from n to 3n.

Comment: Using this method you can make a set of k n-sided dice for any k>2 and n>3.